# Eclipse-Kepler, Java 8 compilation issue "syntax errors on tokens"

Tags: eclipse-kepler

I am using Eclipse Kepler with jdk1.8.0.
I do not face any compilation problems in import statements related to java8 or collect construct. However I get the compilation issue in:- Dish::getName...it says.. Syntax errors on tokens, delete the tokens.

Just trying to run the following code:

```
List<String> dishNames = menu.stream()
                              .map(Dish::getName)
                              .collect(toList());

System.out.println(dishNames);
```

Dish is a java object with String property name.

I have installed JDK8, added the latest JRE in eclipse Java Build Path.
Java compiler compliance.

Any hints what something silly I am missing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if I run that code, I'll get all sorts of errors.  Could you give a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  And most importantly, what is `Dish`?

Comment: Sorry, if that confused you. I was actually facing problem with "::" in Dish::getName , so I missed mentioning the POJO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed installing support of java8 in eclipse kepler.
You can follow this link for detailed instructions.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler

Comment: How silly of me.Thanks for the quick response. When I try to install the update, I get the following error:-Cannot perform operation, will not be installed JDT patch with Java8 support.Any help?

Comment: Can you check which Kepler version are you using from Help? For Kepler you need SR2(4.3.2).